# How to get network response code (javascript)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I recently added a linkedin tag to my website for data tracking very similar to google tag or fb pixels.

For me to know the tag is installed correctly, I would need to inspect the network response and ensure the request code for the fired tag is getting a ‘302 response’.

Is there a hardcoded way of validating the network response without manually using the inspect tool?

I would like to create a chrome extension script that would perform this validation using javascript.

Comment: See chrome.webRequest API.

Comment: chrome.webRequest API ---- works